# Missing Single Page Application template in MVC4 RC

Tags: installation, asp.net-mvc-4, singlepage, asp.net-spa

When I installed MVC4 beta on a development PC, it had a template for SPA (Single Page Application). Today on a different PC with the same setup (VS2010 SP1, win7), I installed [MVC4 RC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29935) but no longer is the SPA template available (see image).  Any one else having this issue? or is this a documented change that I could not find?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Changes from ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta

**The major changes from ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta in this release are summarized below:**

Removed ASP.NET Single Page Application: ASP.NET Single Page Application (SPA) shipped with ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta as an early preview of the experience for building applications that include significant client-side interactions using JavaScript. SPA won’t ship with the final MVC 4 release, but will continue to evolve outside of the MVC 4 release. Check out the ASP.NET SPA home page for details.

...

http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes

P.S., Wow I am glad that I didn't use it for an app I build right now. I was considering it 3 months ago, but decided not to risk it because MS said that it is experimental.

Comment: The answer right in the release notes, Should of read more carefully. I was about to use it for an App. Glad I waited until it came out of beta to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the SPA template in the [Fall 2012 update](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/fall-2012-update). More information on the template [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/19/mvc-single-page-template-update-for-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc.aspx) and [here](http://www.johnpapa.net/inside-the-asp-net-single-page-apps-template/).

Answer (score 0):

It`s very risky now

For example if you try to run it with System.json for serialization it runs well with WebApi and DBDATAContext methods but it`s impossible to use it with Entities relationship entity circular errors and so on. (There is a solution to change private access of method get, but would be too much work to have to change in all the access methos of all your entities.